# Erdas Imagine Error: Performance warning: Covariance calculation requires stack processing but input layer stack isn't suitable. How to solve it?

Tags: error, classification, erdas-imagine

I am collecting signatures right now and when I am adding them to the Signature Editor Erdas says:

> Performance warning: Covariance calculation requires stack  processing
>   but input layer stack isn't suitable

How do I solve it, since I am using a stacked and georeferenced source layer already?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Erdas Imagine 2015?

I had the same problem as you when I was trying to run an unsupervised classification. I went to another computer that had Erdas Imagine 2011 installed. I then ran an unsupervised classification with the same exact parameters on the same image. No error message and the classification went smoothly.

It wouldn't surprise me if this was a bug that was introduced in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

this problem arises when we haven't use directly a stacked images, except this we use some processed image like from ATCOR or FLASH generated. If use directly a raw stacked images .img file then this problem doesn't arise